# lua how to detect unused require

Tags: lua

I know lua has tools such as lualink and luacheck but none of those mark unused "require".  I know other dynamic languages such as python have tools that specifically check and some even remove unused imports from source files.

Does lua have any tools or such functionality?

Comment: If you're requiring modules like this: `local lib = require "lib"` then anything that checks for unused locals should pick it up.

Comment: i guess that means you can simply use lualint and luacheck

Answer (score 0):

as Colonel said...

If you define your libraries with local variables you can use luacheck/lint to determine unused variables